# Classification Scores differ between H2O4GPU and Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, h2o, h2o4gpu

I've begun evaluating a random forest classifier using precision and recall. However, despite the train and test sets being identical for the CPU and GPU implementations of the classifier, I'm seeing differences in the returned evaluation scores. Is this a known bug within the library by chance?

Both code samples are below for reference.

**Scikit-Learn (CPU)**

```
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, precision_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rf_cpu = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5000, n_jobs=-1)
rf_cpu.fit(X_train, y_train)
rf_cpu_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

recall_score(rf_cpu_pred, y_test)
precision_score(rf_cpu_pred, y_test)

CPU Recall: 0.807186
CPU Precision: 0.82095
```

**H2O4GPU (GPU)**

```
from h2o4gpu.metrics import recall_score, precision_score
from h2o4gpu import RandomForestClassifier

rf_gpu = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5000, n_gpus=1)
rf_gpu.fit(X_train, y_train)
rf_gpu_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

recall_score(rf_gpu_pred, y_test)
precision_score(rf_gpu_pred, y_test)

GPU Recall: 0.714286
GPU Precision: 0.809988
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction: Realized the inputs for precision and recall were in the wrong order. The order is always `(y_true, y_pred)`, per the Scikit-Learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html).

**Corrected Evaluation Code**

```
recall_score(y_test, rf_gpu_pred)
precision_score(y_test, rf_gpu_pred)
```

Comment: Did that change the values/results?

Comment: @AndreasMueller It actually did...for whatever reason, the Scikit-Learn numbers are now much lower (precision ~0.6, recall ~0.6). H2O4GPU numbers are a touch higher.

Comment: can you try using the same scoring function both times just to make sure? But I imagine the main difference is in hyperparameters.